# MySQL Schemas not showing on Work Bench

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

My schemas in the MySQL Workbench is not showing up. I tried with multiple users and granted all privileges to all users, yet nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously created two connections for two different databases. One was for a university project which I didn't want touched.

[image: Bottom right]

The wrong MySQL instance was running, which meant I couldn't see the schemas. So I had to start the correct service from the bottom right icon.